# On button click select prev() div

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the below function? I am trying to change the css of the prev() div on the click of the #up button. (I know this is noob stuff) Thanks

```
$.fn.expand = function() {
        $('#up').click(function() {
         $("#frame.#two").previousSibling().css("height" , "80%");
        }
        });
```

Comment: I don't think `#frame.#two` is a valid selector (or it would search for an element with ID `frame` and **class** `#two`, so just use `#two`). And `previousSibling()` is not a jQuery function, it's `prev()` as you already mentioned in your question.

Comment: If you want to use previousSibling, index into the jquery wrapped object then append previousSibling as a property (not a method): $('#id')[0].previousSibling;

Answer (score 0):

For one, you have a syntax error, it should be:

```
$.fn.expand = function() {
        $('#up').click(function() {
         $("#frame.#two").previousSibling().css("height" , "80%");
        });
}
```

Assuming that you already defined `previousSibling()` somewhere in your code.

Comment: previousSibling is not defined. I am trying to get the prev() sibling of #two. I think the answer is along the lines of Felx King with 

$(#two).prev().css("height" , "80%");